# Pandas data frame - Group a column values then Randomize new values of that column

Tags: python, pandas

I have one column (X) that contains some values with duplicates (several rows have the same value and they all are sequenced).
I have a requirement to randomize new values for that columns for testing one issue. so I tried:

```
np.random.seed(RSEED)
df["X"] = np.random.randint(100, 500, df.shape[0])
```

But this is not enough, I need to keep the sequences, I mean to group by same value then to randomize for all of the rows of that value a new number, and to do it for all grouped values of the original column. e.g.

| X | new X (randomized) |
| --- | --- |
| 210 | 500 |
| 210 | 500 |
| . | . |
| . | . |
| 340 | 100 |
| 340 | 100 |
| . | . |
| . | . |

I started looking if Pandas has something built-in, I can group by `pandas.DataFrame.groupBy` but couldn't find a `pandas.DataFrame.random` that can be applied for the same group.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple approach is to use groupby and transform to broadcast random integers per group

```
df.groupby('X')['X'].transform(lambda _: np.random.randint(100, 500))
```

---

```
0    137
1    137
2    .
3    .
4    335
5    335
Name: X, dtype: int64
```